# Pass Array of values PHP to JQuery script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I don't know if this is even possible but I figure it's worth asking. Basically I need to pass an`Array` of values from a `php` web page to the underlying `JQuery`.

The `Array` contains a list of all the users in the `database` and I want to populate a `dropdown` with these users.

This is my `php` page: (with `html`)

```
<form action="<?the_permalink()?>" method="post">
    <div id="summary">
     <?php wp_dropdown_users(array('name' => 'CMP Member') ); ?> 
    <table id="ordertable">
        <tr><th>Product</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Bulk</th>
        <th>Options</th>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <!-- Comments Box -->
    Comments<br/>
    <textarea name="comments"></textarea><br/>
    <input name="product_list" id="products_field" type="hidden" value="<?= isset($_POST['product_list'])?$_POST['product_list']:'' ?>">
    Next Day Delivery <input type="checkbox" name="next-day-delivery" value="yes" />
    <input type="submit" value="Confirm Order" class="confirmBtn"/>
    </div>
    </form>
```

This is my `JQuery`

```
$this = $(this);

//If the cookie exists get a reference to the array it contains (productArray)
if($.cookie('order_cookie') != undefined){
    productArray = JSON.parse($.cookie('order_cookie'));
    $.cookie('order_cookie', JSON.stringify(productArray), { expires: 1, path: '/' });
    $('#products_field').val(encodeURIComponent($.cookie('order_cookie')));//Add to hidden field
}

//Reference to the order table
var ordertable = document.getElementById("ordertable");
//Loop through the Array and display in the table
for(var i = 0; i < productArray.length; i ++){
    //Check if a dropdown is required in bulk order...
    if(productArray[i].bulk == 'true'){
    var bulk = "<select><option value='...'>...</option></select>";
    }else{
    var bulk = "";
    }

    var productRow;
    productRow = '<tr>';
    productRow += '<td>' + productArray[i].stockCode + '</td>';
    productRow += '<td>' + productArray[i].quantity + '</td>';
    productRow += '<td>' + bulk + '</td>'; <-- Want to put dropdown here!
    productRow += '<td><input type="button" value="-" class="removeBtn"/>'
    productRow += '<input type="button" value="+" class="addBtn"/>'
    productRow += '<input type="button" value="Delete" class="deleteBtn"/></td>'
    productRow += '</tr>'
    $('#ordertable tr:last').after(productRow);
}
```

If anyone has any suggestions on how to go about doing this I'd appreciate it

Comment: If those users are in the drop-down they become accessible to the jQuery code.

Comment: I'm confused - why would you want to populate a dropdown with jQuery if you already get a populated drop-down from PHP?

Comment: You should think seriously about using an autocomplete instead of a drop down.

Comment: @MarcinWolny, the dropdown is created using `Wordpress` function `<?php wp_dropdown_users(array('name' => 'Member') ); ?>`. It creates the dropdown, thing is I'd like this dropdown to be displayed on certain `rows` of the table, not all of them. I was checking a condition in `Jquery` to enable this